# jquery colorbox plugin background color

Tags: jquery, colorbox

The colorbox image has an immediate background surround which is normally white in the examples. I emphasize that I am not talking about the dark background overlay. Although it seems an obvious requirement, there seems to be nothing in the settings that covers customizing this background color so how would I do that without diving into the plugin code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your stylesheet to override the plugin background color

```
#colorbox {
    background-color: #FFF; /* Add a color of your choice */
}
```

Comment: That simple! Can't imagine why I didn't try it. Many thanks for responding